# Ruby: Why calling the superclass method on an object gives an error

Tags: ruby

> Class `A` is a subclass of Class `B`. Class `B` is a subclass of class `C`. `a` is an object of class `A`. `b` is an object of class `B`. Which ONE of the following Ruby expressions is NOT true?
>
> 1. `b.respond_to?('class')`
> 2. `a.superclass == b.class`
> 3. `A.superclass == B`
> 4. `a.class.ancestors.include?(C)`

The answer to this quiz question was (2).

I understand why (1), (3), and (4) are correct, but (2) is a bit confusing.

(2) is confusing because when I input `a.superclass` into `irb`, I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'superclass' for #<A:0x7fbdce1075f0>`.

But when I input `A.superclass == B` into the `irb`, I get `true`.

Why can I call `superclass` on a class but not on the class's object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class C
end

class B < C
end

class A < B
end

a = A.new
b = B.new

p b.class
p a.superclass


--output:--
B

1.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method `superclass' for #<A:0x0000010109bc88> (NoMethodError)
```

> Why can I call superclass on a class but not on the *class's object*?

First, the proper term is "an instance of A".  The reason you can call superclass() on A is because ruby defines a class called Class, and Class defines the methods that can be called by class objects, which are instances of Class.  All classes, e.g. A, are instances of Class.  One of the methods defined in Class is superclass().

On the other hand, an instance of A is not a class, and therefore an instance of A cannot call methods defined in Class.

You might have read that "everything in ruby is an object" (which is not true, but in most cases it is).  So A is an object (in addition to being a class).  An object must be an instance of some class, and it so happens that A is an instance of Class.  Therefore, A can call the methods defined in Class.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! The quiz problem said `a` is an _object_ of class `A`. Is this inaccurate or imprecise, and `a` is an _instance_ of `A` would be more accurate?

Comment: The phrase 'a is an object of class A' is also correct, but not 'a is a class object'.  I guess saying "class's object" is technically correct when taking about an instance of a class, but it is confusing since it looks and sounds too much like 'class object'.  In ruby "a class object" is A or B or C.